# how to create an <a> link tag in a page that uses angular js routing?

Tags: html, angularjs, hyperlink, routes

I'm using Angular JS routing.

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
 app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when("/", {
   templateUrl : "index.htm"
   })
  .when("/second", {
  templateUrl : "second.html",
  controller : "secondCtrl"
  })
  .when("/third", {
  templateUrl : "third.html",
  controller : "thirdCtrl"
  });
 });
 app.controller("secondCtrl", function ($scope) {
   $scope.msg = "in second controller";
 });
 app.controller("thirdCtrl", function ($scope) {
   $scope.msg = "in third controller";
 });
```

how can a create a  link in my html to link to the /second link in the routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question.

A link in the form of the following can be used to access the /second route in the above example.

```
 <a href="#!/second" >Second</a>
```